# How to add buttons in ZXing Scanner View?

Tags: java, android, qr-code

I already found this [How to add buttons in Zxing Scanner Camera View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43518388/how-to-add-buttons-in-zxing-scanner-camera-view)
But it's doesn't work ... 
I use a camera in a pop up window like this

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int width =dm.widthPixels;
    int height =dm.heightPixels;
    getWindow().setLayout((int)(width*.9), (int)(height*.7));

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
    params.x =0;
    params.y = -20;
    getWindow().setAttributes(params);

    mScannerView = (ZXingScannerView) findViewById(R.id.zxscan);
    mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
    mScannerView.startCamera();
```

And this is xml file

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#CFD8DC"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.adisi.turzilnic.S1">

 <me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView
    android:id="@+id/zxscan"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/FlashOFF"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/flashoff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/FlashON"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/flashon"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>

 </me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

What is wrong here? I don't understand.. My buttons aren't shown on camera.. Should be from that pop up? I set the buttons with margintop and marginleft on the middle because I wanted to see if the positions it's the problem.. but the same problem ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of your buttons is **wrap_content** and instead of setting the image source on the button you are setting the image on the background. The view relative sizes don't keep track of your view's background so you will most probably have a view with width/height set to 0.

Try to set the images using **"src"** instead.

Comment: Still with the same problem .. I can see the buttons for 1 second and then disappear ..

Comment: Have you tried to extract the buttons outside of the ZXingScannerView and put them directly in the RelativeLayout?