# How to add button in Zxing Scanner Camera View?

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing

I want to add a button in Zxing Scanner Camera View, tried many procedures and seen many answers related to add button in Zxing library and refered this " [How to add buttons in Zxing Scanner Camera View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43518388/how-to-add-buttons-in-zxing-scanner-camera-view) " , but it's  not working anyone guide me, Thanks in advance, My code is

MainActivity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;
final static String serverUrl = "";
private ZXingScannerView scannerView;
String res;
ImageButton img;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.e("OnCreate", "OnCreated");

    //ZXingScannerView zxing=(ZXingScannerView)findViewById(R.id.zxscan);
    scannerView = (ZXingScannerView) findViewById(R.id.zxscan);
    img=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.img1);
    //scannerView.setResultHandler(this);
    //scannerView.startCamera();

    //zxing.addView(scannerView);
    //setContentView(scannerView);




    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkPermission()) {
            Log.e("M", "Permission");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission already granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Log.e("R", "Permission");
            requestPermission();
        }
    }
}

private boolean checkPermission() {
    return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}

private void requestPermission() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA);
}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CAMERA:
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                Log.e("Successfull", "Success");

                boolean cameraAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                if (cameraAccepted) {
                    Log.e("accpt", "Accpt");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Granted, Now you can access camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Log.e("ntaccpt", "Not Acpt");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Denied, You cannot access and camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(CAMERA)) {
                            showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access to both the permissions",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                                requestPermissions(new String[]{CAMERA},
                                                        REQUEST_CAMERA);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}

private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
    new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            .create()
            .show();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    int capi = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (capi >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkPermission()) {
            if (scannerView == null) {
                scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
                setContentView(scannerView);
            }
            scannerView.setResultHandler(this);
            scannerView.startCamera();
        } else {
            requestPermission();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    scannerView.stopCamera();
    scannerView = null;
}

@Override
public void handleResult(final Result result) {

    res = result.getText();
    Log.d("Scanner Result", result.getText());
    Log.d("Scanner Result", result.getBarcodeFormat().toString());

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            scannerView.resumeCameraPreview(MainActivity.this);
        }
    });
    builder.setNeutralButton("Send", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            GetText();
            scannerView.resumeCameraPreview(MainActivity.this);
        }
    });

    builder.setMessage(result.getText());
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

}

public void GetText()  //throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{

    String data = res;
    String text = "";
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    Log.e("Datafirst", data);
    String requesturi = serverUrl + data;
    // Send data
    try {

        URL url = new URL(requesturi);
        Log.e("DataSecond", requesturi);

         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(data);
        wr.flush();
        Log.e("Data Third", data);

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Readed Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Readed Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        text = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("Exceptionio", "Error", ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {

            reader.close();
            Log.e("Closed", "Closed");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Except2", "Error", ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Log.e("setText", data);

}


}
```

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView
    android:id="@+id/zxscan"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/img1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:src="@drawable/imgbut"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: A bit off-topic but just a pro tip: Use [Google Mobile Vision API](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision) for better, faster scanning (And Use [this](https://github.com/KingsMentor/MobileVisionBarcodeScanner) to skip the boiler plate of the same).

Comment: I uploaded a solution, you can see it at https://stackoverflow.com/a/77497497/5486945

Answer (score 0):

Try my code, It will look like this

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.package.name.TakeSingleScanActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">




<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbarAdjustScan"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="56dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleToolbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/searchAdjustBtn"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="SEARCH   "
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="13dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:text="Point at any barcode to scan"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="normal" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginBottom="120dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textv"
    android:id="@+id/relative_scan_take_single"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/doneBtn"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="Done"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="22dp" />


</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java code for Scanner :**

```
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_take_single_scan);
        init();

    }

private void init() {

        //Scanner
        mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_scan_take_single);
        rl.addView(mScannerView);
        mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        mScannerView.startCamera();
        mScannerView.setSoundEffectsEnabled(true);
        mScannerView.setAutoFocus(true);

    }

 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mScannerView.setResultHandler(this); // Register ourselves as a handler for scan results.
        mScannerView.startCamera();          // Start camera on resume
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mScannerView.stopCamera();           // Stop camera on pause
    }


@Override
    public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
        // Do something with the result here
        Log.e(TAG, rawResult.getText()); // Prints scan results
        Log.e(TAG, rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString());

        Log.e("SCAN_RESULT", "" + rawResult.getText());
        //dataSingle.put("0",rawResult.getText());

    }
```

Comment: tried this code with my xml file not working only camera view is showing

Comment: could i update my answer with java codes too @Kumararaja